# I can not take a critical section

Tags: windows, multithreading, locking, blocking, critical-section

I have a thread stopped taking a critical section. The critical section does not have any thread owning, the only strange thing is that LockCount is -3.

- LockCount -3
- RecursionCount 0
- OwningThread 0
- LockSemaphore dfc
- SpinCount 10000

Inside debug info the ContentionCount is 1.

How can I get a lockCount of -3? any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: The most likely cause is that you are calling LeaveCriticalSection when you don't own it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You released it more times than you acquired it.
It's a good idea to use a scoped guard to auto-release it. Then you don't have to worry about multi release.